# Calling a function when undoing or redoing in a Text widget

Tags: python, text, tkinter, undo-redo

I know that you can set `undo=True` for a `Text` widget, and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> for undo and redo.

But I was wondering if there was a function I could bind to a button or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you rephrase or be more specific in what you want to do?

Comment: You mean, you want to bind a `Button` widget in the GUI to undo/redo? That seems like a really annoying way to undo/redo. May I ask why you want this feature?

Comment: This article might also be useful to understand better how undos and redos work: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-undo-stack.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text widget has both an `edit_undo()` and `edit_redo()` method, which is what the built-in bindings use. You can call these methods from a button or menu item if you wish.